# how to solve unhandled exception error when using visual C++ 2008?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, exception

Could someone please help me to solve unhandled exception error when using visual C++ 2008? the error is displayed as follow: Unhandled exception at 0x00411690 in time.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000008

Some details:
-       tm  0x00000000 {tm_sec=??? tm_min=??? tm_hour=??? ...}  tm *
        tm_sec  CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated
                    ...

Actually when I used visual c++ 6 in the past, there weren't any  error and the program was running fine. But now ehen I use visual 2008, I am getting this Unhandled exception  error.

Here is the program:

```
...
int gettimeofday(struct timeval *tv, struct timezone *tz)
{
  FILETIME ft;
  unsigned __int64 tmpres = 0;
  static int tzflag = 0;

  if (NULL != tv)
  {
    GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&ft);

    tmpres |= ft.dwHighDateTime;
    tmpres <<= 32;
    tmpres |= ft.dwLowDateTime;

    tmpres /= 10;  /*convert into microseconds*/
    /*converting file time to unix epoch*/
    tmpres -= DELTA_EPOCH_IN_MICROSECS; 
    tv->tv_sec = (long)(tmpres / 1000000UL);
    tv->tv_usec = (long)(tmpres % 1000000UL);
  }

  if (NULL != tz)
  {
    if (!tzflag)
    {
      _tzset();
      tzflag++;
    }
    tz->tz_minuteswest = _timezone / 60;
    tz->tz_dsttime = _daylight;
  }

  return 0;
}


uint32_t stampstart()
{
 struct timeval  tv;
 struct timezone tz;
 struct tm      *tm;
 uint32_t         start;

 gettimeofday(&tv, &tz);
 tm = localtime(&tv.tv_sec);

 printf("TIMESTAMP-START\t  %d:%02d:%02d:%d (~%d ms)\n", tm->tm_hour,
        tm->tm_min, tm->tm_sec, tv.tv_usec,
        tm->tm_hour * 3600 * 1000 + tm->tm_min * 60 * 1000 +
        tm->tm_sec * 1000 + tv.tv_usec / 1000);   /////---debugger stops here---

 start = tm->tm_hour * 3600 * 1000 + tm->tm_min * 60 * 1000 +
  tm->tm_sec * 1000 + tv.tv_usec / 1000;

 return (start);

}
```

thanks for your replies:

Comment: Use the Visual Studio debugger, step into the code, and tell us where the exception happens...

Comment: On which line you're getting this exception...?

Comment: Thanks for replies ... see the line :      tm->tm_sec * 1000 + tv.tv_usec / 1000); of uint32_t stampstart() function

Comment: the problem is that the variable " tv.tv_sec "  returns a negative value. why? is ther any idea? thanks

Comment: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494356/how-to-use-gettimeofday-or-something-equivalent-with-visual-studio-c-2008

Answer (score 2):

Try Something like...

```
 tm = localtime(&tv.tv_sec);
if(tm)
{
 printf("TIMESTAMP-START\t  %d:%02d:%02d:%d (~%d ms)\n", tm->tm_hour,
        tm->tm_min, tm->tm_sec, tv.tv_usec,
        tm->tm_hour * 3600 * 1000 + tm->tm_min * 60 * 1000 +
        tm->tm_sec * 1000 + tv.tv_usec / 1000); 

 start = tm->tm_hour * 3600 * 1000 + tm->tm_min * 60 * 1000 +
  tm->tm_sec * 1000 + tv.tv_usec / 1000;
}
else
{
 // failed to retrive local time
}
```

Comment: thanks for the idea. yes! it fails to retrieve local time. Is there idea on how to solve this problem? thanks again for your help

Comment: you can see errno for exact problem...if localtime()  failed it will set errno ...

Comment: yes! it is localtime as it doesn't returns anythink. actually i don't understand why it works with VC++6 and not with VC++2008 ...thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The access violation refers address 0x00000008, which probably means that your code is accessing a field at offset 8 in a struct to which you point with a NULL pointer.
I guess that localtime returns a NULL pointer.  Check this.

Comment: Probably, but why it works with VC++6 and not with VC++2008? thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

"Access violation reading location 0x00000008"

An address that low is probably caused by accessing a null pointer.  In this case, `tm` is probably 0 because of a problem with `localtime` or `gettimeofday`.  You get address 0x08 instead of 0x00 because the compiler is trying to read a value 8 bytes into the struct.

Comment: I think this is the cause as well, but I need to read the time ... thanks for reply!

Answer (score 1):

The type of member `tv.tv_sec` is `long`, but `localtime` expects a `time_t *` parameter. In VC6 this worked because both `long` and `time_t` were 32-bit, but in VS2008 `time_t` is a 64-bit type so they are incompatible.

This should fix it:

```
//add to beginning of stampstart function:
time_t t;

//... other code...

//put this instead of call to localtime:
t = tv.tv_sec;
tm = localtime(&t);
```

Comment: Actually i already tried this : tm = localtime((time_t *) &tv.tv_sec); and still getting the same error (exception handling)...

Comment: @make: I forgot this is C, so the variables have to be declared at the beginning of the function. I edited my answer to show this. As for your second comment, casting it to `time_t*` won't help because it doesn't have an actual `time_t` to point to.

Comment: thanks! yes you are right as I remenbered just after i replied to your message that it is C. yes! i tried this also and still getting the same error ... any other ideas... thanks again for your help

Comment: @make: By "same error" do you mean C2275 or access violation?

Comment: I mean the unhandled exception... here is a copy : 

First-chance exception at 0x0041166a in tim.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000008. Unhandled exception at 0x0041166a in tim.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000008.

Answer (score 0):

With that address, my SWAG is that tm is NULL. Since you never check for the NULL after the call to localtime(), you are dereferencing a NULL pointer.

Edit: SWAG = Scientific Wild Ass Guess.

The address 0x00000008 is the same offset of tm.tm_hour. You are trying to access tm->tm_hour when you pass in the parameter to printf().

Comment: which swag are you talking about ...? I get error when I run the executable. the program is compiled and linked without errors. but when I execute it, I get unhandled exception  ... thanks for reply!

Comment: "Specific while ass guess" :)  And it would compile cleanly, because the compiler has no way of knowing that `tm` is going to end up null when you run the program.  That can't happen until you execute.

Comment: thanks for reply. actually I don't have experience with visual C++ and it is the first time I heared about SWAG.So please explain and tell me how to use to solve this poblem ... thanks again

Answer (score 0):

To catch this kind of exception a minor project tweaking is needed. Just enable /EHa option in project settings. See **Project Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Modify the Enable C++ Exceptions to "Yes With SEH Exceptions"**. That's it!

See details here:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1deeycx5(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1deeycx5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)