# Cross Platform way to get the time of day?

Tags: c++, c, cross-platform

Is there a simple way to get time time of day (17:30, 01:20...etc) that would work on iOS, OSX, Linux and Windows?

If not is there a Windows way and a posix way or something?

Thanks

Comment: You can try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494356/how-to-use-gettimeofday-or-something-equivalent-with-visual-studio-c-2008), and POSIX has `gettimeofday`

Comment: If you have to cross a platform just to get the time well that's just silly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can retrieve the time with `time_t now = time(NULL);` or `time(&now);`

You then usually convert to local time with `struct tm *tm_now = localtime(&now);`. A `struct tm` contains fields for the year, month, day, day of week, hour, minute, and second. If you want to produce printable output, `strftime` supports that directly.

Both of these are in the C and C++ standards, so they are available on most normal platforms.

If you really only care about C++, you can use `std::put_time`, which is similar to `strftime`, but a little bit simpler to use for the typical case of writing the output to a stream.

Comment: the op ask time of the day......

Comment: @NicholasJela: Yes. And as noted, the struct tm contains fields for the current hour, minute and second. Is that not what you'd think of as time of day?

Answer (score 5):

with C++11 you can use

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    std::time_t t = std::time(nullptr);
    std::cout << "UTC:   " << std::put_time(std::gmtime(&t), "%c %Z") << '\n'
              << "local: " << std::put_time(std::localtime(&t), "%c %Z") << '\n';
}
```

which should produce on (any platform)

> UTC:   Wed Dec 28 11:47:03 2011 GMT
>
> local: Wed Dec 28 06:47:03 2011 EST

though `std::put_time()` (from `iomanip`) is not yet implemented in, say, gcc 4.7.0.

Comment: It was added with GCC 5.0