# std::put_time implementation status in GCC?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, std, c++-chrono

I was trying to compile [this example program](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point) using GCC (tested versions 4.5.1, 4.6.3, 4.8.4):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>

using std::chrono::system_clock;

int main()
{
    system_clock::time_point now = system_clock::now();
    std::time_t now_c = system_clock::to_time_t(
                            now - std::chrono::hours(24));
    std::cout << "One day ago, the time was "
              << std::put_time(std::localtime(&now_c), "%F %T") << '\n';
}
```

[But it tells me:](http://ideone.com/XR1eF4)

```
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:14:18: error: 'put_time' is not a member of 'std'
```

---

I thought, probably it's not implemented yet. So I tried to check the implementation status for this function. I only found this page:

- http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html

but there I could not find any note on `put_time` or `chrono` or alike. Can anyone point me to a resource that provides information on the implementation status for this library?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

See [TODO extended iomanip manipulators std::get_time and std::put_time](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54354) for gcc 4.8.0.

See also [Cross Platform way to get the time of day?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11096995/341970) claiming that is not implemented in 4.7.0.

---

**UPDATE:** As the gcc developer [Jonathan Wakely confirmed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14136833/stdput-time-implementation-status-in-gcc/14137287?noredirect=1#comment35569824_14142342) below: The `std::get_time` and `std::put_time` manipulators are still missing in gcc 4.9.

---

**UPDATE:** Jonathan Wakely [closed](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54354#c9) this ticket on 22 Dec, 2014:

> Fixed for GCC 5

Thanks [simonwo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3729369/simonwo) for letting me know about it.

Comment: GCC 4.9 has been released - it seems it's neither in there, isn't it?

Comment: @ollo As [Jonathan has confirmed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14136833/stdput-time-implementation-status-in-gcc/14137287?noredirect=1#comment35569824_14142342), gcc 4.9 still lacks these functionalities. :( Yeah, that is sad.

Comment: @ollo Still, it is sad, I would use those manipulators too. :(

Comment: According to the ticket, this is implemented in GCC 5.

Answer (score 20):

You might have noticed the link you gave doesn't list **any** parts of the library! But below the table it says:

> The status of the library implementation can be tracked in this [table](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x)

That table notes that `std::get_time` and `std::put_time` manipulators are not implemented yet.

Edit: `put_time` is now on the GCC development trunk.

Comment: Straight from the developer :)