# How print current time in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, locale, c++-chrono

Is there an easy way in C++11 to print the current wall time using the appropriate formatting rules of the locale associated with the ostream being used?

What I really want to do is something like this:

```
myStream << std::chrono::system_clock::now();
```

and have the date and time printed in accord with whatever locale is associated with `myStream`. C++11 offers `put_time`, but it takes a formatting string, and I want the format to be determined by the locale associate with the stream. There's also `time_put` and `time_put_byname`, but based on the examples at cppreference.com, these functions are used in conjunction with `put_time`.

Is there no simple way to print a timepoint value without manually formatting it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use `put_time` with a format string like `"%c"`. `%c` is the format specifier for the standard date and time string for the locale. The result looks like "Tue Jul 23 19:32:18 CEST 2013" on my machine (POSIX en_US locale, in a German timezone).

```
auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
auto now_c = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);
std::cout << std::put_time(std::localtime(&now_c), "%c") << '\n';
```

Comment: Im surprised with there is no *modern* way to print datetime data. We must use the old-style C APIs. But, well, `std::chrono` is a great advance in datetime matters. But no C++11 way to print time?

Comment: @Manu343726 <chrono_io> (http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/bloomington/chrono_io.html) was not standardised (not sure if it was due to time pressures or for other reasons).

Comment: Not an answer to this question, however the following is I believe further information related to this question:  http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/date_algorithms.html . This link develops algorithms that convert to and from year/month/day triples and all implementations of `system_clock::time_point`.  These algorithms could aid in developing the I/O the OP desires.

Comment: Note: `std::put_time` is NOT supported in gcc < 5.0, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14137287/209882