# Parsing an date/time string with std::get_time needs separators?

Tags: c++, datetime

Is a separator character required to parse a string using std::get_time? I can't find a reference to say that it is. I'm trying to parse an ISO date/time string such as "20140105T123456" - for example:

For example,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <locale>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::tm t = { 0 };

    // fails
    std::istringstream ss("20141105T123456");
    ss >> std::get_time(&t, "%Y%m%dT%H%M%S");

    // works
    //std::istringstream ss("2014 11 05 T 12 34 56");
    //ss >> std::get_time(&t, "%Y %m %d T %H %M %S");

    std::ostringstream os;
    std::cout << std::put_time(&t, "%c") << std::endl;
}
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2013. I tried to build on Linux but the latest version of GCC I have is 4.7.3 which doesn't appear to support get_time yet.

Silly mistake on my part or are separators required?

Comment: I have just hit this issue in visual studio 2016. It is logged here as a bug so please vote it up for a fix:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/2290315

Comment: Even if the format has separators, but input lacks them a debug assertion is raised instead of failing. Bug

Answer (score 6):

According to [the description of second parameter of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time) `std::get_time`, separators are not required.

> The format string consists of zero or more conversion specifiers,
>   whitespace characters, and ordinary characters (except %). Each
>   ordinary character is expected to match one character in the input
>   stream in case-insensitive comparison. Each whitespace character
>   matches arbitrary whitespace in the input string. Each conversion
>   specification begins with % character, optionally followed by E or O
>   modifier (ignored if unsupported by the locale), followed by the
>   character that determines the behavior of the specifier. The format
>   specifiers match the POSIX function strptime()

On my Mac, I use clang++(Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
) to compile your code, and run the program, the output is: `Sun Nov  5 12:34:56 2014`. Acctually, I have  gcc 4.8.2 installed, but it doesn't support the `std::get_time` and `std::put_time`. Then I search the implementation status for this function, and find [that is not implemented in GCC 4.8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14136833/stdput-time-implementation-status-in-gcc)

It did fail in VS2013, after calling `std::get_time`, all the elements in t are just 0. Format specifiers don't do what's expected here on Windows. It's not your mistake.

Comment: Thank you for that analysis - for the moment, I'll insert separators myself before I call `std::get_time`

Answer (score 2):

The reference to the POSIX strptime() function in the standard is causing some confusion.  The POSIX standard specifies that the conversion operators are separated by non-alpha characters.

> The application shall ensure that there is white-space or other non-alphanumeric characters between any two conversion specifications.

The GLIBC version of strptime (and, IMO, any sane implementation) does not require these separators. [http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html -- see the Notes section.]

Requiring separators makes it impossible to parse conforming ISO-8601 date/time basic formats.  As C++ is also an ISO standard, its strptime() function should be able to parse this format.

I think the std::get_time() documentation needs to be clarified to explicitly state that separators shall not be required and justify that statement by pointing to ISO-8601.  It should further be clarified that the POSIX strptime() standard only specifies the conversion specifiers that are required to be supported by a conforming implementation.