# C++ parsing YYMMDD ISO 8601 date string with std::get_time gives unexpected result?

Tags: c++, date-parsing

I'm trying to parse a date formatted as `YYMMDD`. As a test, I've tried the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <locale>
#include <iomanip>

int main(){
    std::tm t = {};
    std::istringstream ss("191203");
    ss >> std::get_time(&t, "%y%m%d");
    if (ss.fail()){ 
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << std::put_time(&t, "%c") << '\n';
    }
}
```

Tested with Coliru, GCC 6.1 (C++17), the output is:

```
Sun Mar  0 00:00:00 1912
```

What I expected is:

```
Mon Dec 3 00:00:00 2019
```

Is there something wrong in the format string?

Comment: I see the same on GCC 6.3.0 - looks like a bug to me (treating `%y` as `%Y` - and if I pass `"20191203"` I get the March 2019 result that we want).  Other bugs include `"19.1203"` with `"%y.%m%d"` -> `Sun Dec  3 00:00:00 1919`, so I think this implementation is in urgent need of a test suite!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21172767/parsing-an-date-time-string-with-stdget-time-needs-separators/21176925

Comment: Update: same test, but parsing `"19"` with format `"%y"` gives output `Sun Jan  0 00:00:00 1919`

Comment: This use of a 2-digit year is *not* a proper ISO 8601 format. [The Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) says the standard requires 4-digit years. To quote: *ISO 8601 prescribes, as a minimum, a four-digit year [YYYY] to avoid the year 2000 problem.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Howard Hinnant's free, open-source date/time library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) like this:

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int
main()
{
    date::sys_days t;
    std::istringstream ss("191203");
    ss >> date::parse("%y%m%d", t);
    if (ss.fail())
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
    else
        std::cout << date::format("%c", t) << '\n';
}
```

It works on gcc 6.1:  http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/gy3wpMXeCoxk9Ykj (as well as other platforms).  Except the correct output is:

```
Tue Dec  3 00:00:00 2019
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The result seems correct, but the parsing fails with the string `"19"` and format `"%y"`. It also fails with `"1912"` and format `"%y%m"`.  If I'm not wrong, these are all ISO 8601 basic date formats.

Comment: @Valeriop84:  All true.  The design of this library has it that the coarsest `std::chrono::time_point` parsable is one with a precision of days, and that any ambiguity in nailing down the intention to a specific day is flagged as a failure.  However this library does have `year` and `year_month` types which could be accepted by the parser and formatter with a little work.  I will give that some thought, thanks.

Comment: I still contend that there is a discrepancy between get_time and put_time (get_time has the weird rules because of Y2K paranoia) and put_time doesn't. So IMO your library is fine. POSIX code will break when 2068 comes around, so who has more future proofability?

Comment: @user7744704:  I'm not a fan of `%y` either.  I followed the POSIX spec when implementing it.  But I don't really recommend its use, and never use it in my own code.  `%y` is perhaps most needed for dealing with legacy files born at a time when the year 2000 was the stuff of science fiction and 4 bytes for storing a year as text seemed extravagant.  Get the thing parsed in and then format it unambiguously with `%Y`. :-)

Comment: Thank you, it would be interesting to obtain ISO 8601 compliance. By the way, `"19"` should parse with `"%C"` format :P

Comment: @Valeriop84:  You can now parse and format `"19"` with `"%y"`, and `"1912"` with `"%y%m"`.  However `"%C"` is still not parsable in isolation.  I don't have a dedicated type to parse it into.  https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/commit/3495c513a1a3bf92289024f692783ab657ed0538

Comment: Thank you, i really appreciate that.

Answer (score -1):

It's not a bug. You've run into an artifact of [Y2K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2000_problem). The `tm_year` in field in the `std::tm` structure contains the number of years since 1900. So naturally whatever value for year you get will be added to 1900. Ancient tools like `date` actually do follow the POSIX spec and behave accordingly:

```
date -d'27 JUN 69' +%Y
1969
date -d'27 JUN 68' +%Y
2068
```

Comment: You've missed that the format specifier was lowercase y, which should read 2 characters for the year (19), giving either 1919 or 2019, but it read 4 characters (1912)