# how to display system current time + 3 minutes?

Tags: c++, ctime

In c++:

- How can I display the system current time (only time without the date) ?
- How can I display current time + 3 minutes?
- Can I do it using `cout`?

Which  libraries or functions to use ?

Comment: Check [`std::chrono::system_clock::now()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/now)

Comment: I use Elven magic. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: This looks like homework

Comment: This looks like not having performed any research.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this example (use c++11 clang 3.6):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::time_t now_c = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now - std::chrono::hours(24));
    std::cout << std::put_time(std::localtime(&now_c), "%T") << std::endl;
    std::time_t later_c = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now - std::chrono::hours(24) + std::chrono::minutes(3));
    std::cout << std::put_time(std::localtime(&later_c), "%T") << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

just use `std::chrono`.

Comment: `std::put_time` is poorly supported, to the extent that [GCC 4.9 doesn't have it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14137287/560648) and neither does clang 3.5.0. So unless you're using, what, MSVS(?) this isn't going to be too helpful.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, at least it's described as a standard function in [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, it's a C++11 feature. I just said that it is poorly supported, and I stand by that statement. It's great that cppreference.com is accurate to the letter of the standard, and I suppose that's helpful if you're going to start a career as a cppreference.com contributor... but, for all other C++ use, not so much.

Comment: I use Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.51) (based on LLVM 3.5svn) and it seem to work well.