# c++ error: Function 'get_time' could not be resolved - Ubuntu g++

Tags: c++, ubuntu, std

I have the following piece of C++ code on my class, to convert a ISO 8601 string to a `time_t` structure:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>


.... class code...


struct tm tempTime;
std::stringstream ss(data);
ss >> std::get_time(&tempTime, "%FT%TZ");
std::time_t time = mktime(&tempTime);

.... class code...
```

But the compiler insists on giving me the following error:

```
Function 'get_time' could not be resolved
```

According to [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/get_time/), `std::get_time` should be included with `iomanip`

I supposed all I had to do was to include `iomanip`... Am I missing something here ?

I´m running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: the page you linked says it's a C++11 feature. are you sure you are using the right compiler?

Comment: Yes... C++11 is turned on: `g++ -std=c++0x `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the bottom of [this bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54354#c9) Jonathan Wakely reports it's available from GCC 5.  You can use `g++ --version` to check your version.  (Should be `std::tm tenpTime` FWIW).

Answer (score 2):

The developer himself says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14136833/stdput-time-implementation-status-in-gcc/14142342#14142342) it's not implemented yet, but seems to be implemented in GCC 5 now so you need to find an upgrade.