# Why does std::put_time not compile using multiple compilers?

Tags: c++, c++11, raspberry-pi, g++, llvm-clang

`std::put_time` does not seem to work.

The following snippet is taken [directly from en.cpp.reference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    std::time_t t = std::time(nullptr);
    std::tm tm = *std::localtime(&t);
    std::cout.imbue(std::locale("ru_RU.utf8"));
    std::cout << "ru_RU: " << std::put_time(&tm, "%c %Z") << '\n';
    std::cout.imbue(std::locale("ja_JP.utf8"));
    std::cout << "ja_JP: " << std::put_time(&tm, "%c %Z") << '\n';
}
```

Several compilers agree that put_time is not a member of the std library. My question is; why? Does put_time work, and if so, with which compilers and options does the example compile successfully?

clang++ 3.5.0-10 (based on LLVM 3.5.0) with -std=c++14 complains thus:

```
main.cc:10:36: error: no member named 'put_time' in namespace 'std'
    std::cout << "ru_RU: " << std::put_time(&tm, "%c %Z") << '\n';
                              ~~~~~^
main.cc:12:36: error: no member named 'put_time' in namespace 'std'
    std::cout << "ja_JP: " << std::put_time(&tm, "%c %Z") << '\n';
                              ~~~~~^
2 errors generated.
```

Gcc added support for std::put_time in version 5.0, as stated here by [Jonathan Wakely](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54354#c9).

A [third "compiler" (using cpp.sh)](http://www.cpp.sh/6ynft) and ticking c++14, gives:

```
 In function 'int main()':
10:31: error: 'put_time' is not a member of 'std'
12:31: error: 'put_time' is not a member of 'std'
```

I'm trying to compile this on a raspberry pi; full compiler version info:

```
pi@tacarmepi:~/test$ clang++ --version
Raspbian clang version 3.5.0-10+rpi1 (tags/RELEASE_350/final) (based on LLVM 3.5.0)
Target: arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [std::put\_time implementation status in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14136833/stdput-time-implementation-status-in-gcc)

Comment: Thank you Rakete; that explains why my g++ version 4.9.2 was not sufficient. The question may still be answered completely by specifying which compilers actually support the feature. In particular, I want to use clang, whose llvm page claims that the feature should be implemented as of Clang 3.3.

Comment: I guess, but I don't think that is on-topic. Anyways, are you sure that you are using LLVM's Standard Library instead of gcc's? Because you need a compiler flag for that in clang last time I checked.

Comment: Unsure; so you mean I should not try `clang++ -std=c++1z main.cc` but `clang++ -std=c++1z -stdlib=libstdc++ main.cc` or  `clang++ -std=c++1z -stdlib=libc++ main.cc`? I've tried both; libc++ fails to find iostream, libstdc++ fails the same way as without passing any library option.

Comment: `-stdlib=libc++` is indeed the right option, not sure why it can't find `<iostream>` though...