# C++11: "put_time is not a member of std" on Modern g++

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

I am having an old problem on a new compiler.  While trying to print the current time using `std::chrono` I receive the following error:

```
src/main.cpp:51:30: error: ‘put_time’ is not a member of ‘std’
                 std::cout << std::put_time(std::localtime(&time), "%c") << "\n\n";
                              ^~~
```

The offending snippet is nothing special:

```
#include <chrono>
...
auto time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(std::chrono::system_clock::now());
std::cout << std::put_time(std::localtime(&time), "%c") << "\n\n";
```

This looks an awful lot like the errors being returned in the GCC 4.x series, as referenced all over the place:

- [std::put_time implementation status in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14136833/stdput-time-implementation-status-in-gcc)
- [Why does std::put_time not compile using multiple compilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44930645/why-does-stdput-time-not-compile-using-multiple-compilers)
- https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54354

The only problem with this theory is that my GCC is modern:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 6.3.1 20161221 (Red Hat 6.3.1-1)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I also checked that my application is linking against the appropriate libraries:

```
$ ldd build/myapp
        ...
        libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fde97e7b000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fde97595000)
```

Finally, there is nothing exotic going on in my compile flags:

```
g++ -g -Wall -Werror -std=c++11 -Wno-sign-compare src/main.cpp -c -o obj/main.o
```

Everything I can think to check indicates that this should be working.  So, in short, what gives?

Comment: Your snippet fails to include the header that declares `std::put_time`.

Comment: Whoops, good point.  I have `#include <chrono>` up top.  Question has been updated.  Also, it is not complaining about any of the other time operations such as `std::localtime` and `to_time_t`.

Comment: Well, that would seem to be the problem. `std::put_time` is declared in `<iomanip>`.

Comment: Yeah, this is embarrassing.  That was totally it.  Will accept your answer in 4 minutes.  Well, hopefully this will help future searches.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is that you included the wrong header. `std::put_time` is declared in `<iomanip>`, not `<chrono>`.

---

> Also, it is not complaining about any of the other time operations such as `std::localtime` and `to_time_t`.

`std::localtime` is declared in `<ctime>`.